# Laravel 5.8 Trying to get property 'unreadNotifications' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

Working on my friend's code, it seems all features like Post, Tag, Category, etc are working fine. I want to add a feature to upload a pdf and download it from front end. After adding DownloadController and Downloads model, It shows varies errors. Most irritating error is

```
Trying to get property 'unreadNotifications' of non-object(View: /var/www/html/tes/resources/views/admin/layouts/header.blade.php)
```

Routes:

```
//Admin Routes
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin'], function (){
Route::get('admin/home','HomeController@index')->name('admin.index');

//Users Routes
Route::resource('admin/user','UserController');

//Roles Routes
Route::resource('admin/role','RoleController');

//permissions Routes
Route::resource('admin/permission','PermissionController');

//Download Manager Routes - CV

Route::resource('admin/cv','Downloadcontroller');

//Post Routes
Route::DELETE('postDeleteSelected','PostController@deleteSelected')->name('deleteSelected');
Route::get('admin/post/remove/{post}','PostController@remove')->name('posts.remove');
Route::get('admin/post/trash','PostController@trashed')->name('posts.trashed');
Route::get('admin/post/recover/{id}','PostController@recover')->name('posts.recover');
Route::get('markAsRead','PostController@markRead')->name('markRead');
Route::resource('admin/post','PostController');



//Tag Routes
Route::resource('admin/tag','TagController');

//Category Routes

Route::resource('admin/category','CategoryController');



//Admin Auth Routes
Route::get('admin-login','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('admin-login','Auth\LoginController@login');
});
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Model\admin\admin;
use App\Model\user\Downloads;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Notifications\TaskCompleted;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class Downloadcontroller extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.cv.show');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = new  Downloads;
    if ($request->file('file')){
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file->move('storage/'.$filename);

        $data->file = $filename;
    }
    $data->title = $request->title;
    $data->description = $request->description;
    $data->uploader = Auth::user()->name;
    $data->save();

    $users = admin::where('id','3')->get();
    Notification::send($users, new TaskCompleted($data));
    return redirect(route('cv.index'))->with('toast_success','Post Created Successfully');
}
```

View: in admin.cv.show, the template extends the admin.layouts.app. and the problematic view is here.

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
            @if (Auth::check())
            @if(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->count())
            <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">{{auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->count()}}</span>
            @endif
                @endif
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
            <span class="dropdown-item dropdown-header">
                <a href="{{route('markRead')}}">Mark All as Read</a>
            </span>
            @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="background-color: lightgrey">
                     <p><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>{{$notification->data['data']}}
                         <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">{{$notification->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span>
                     </p>

                </a>
                @endforeach
            @foreach(auth()->user()->readNotifications->take(5) as $notification)
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    <p><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>{{$notification->data['data']}}
                        <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
                    </p>

                </a>
            @endforeach




            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Have you checked you User model? unreadNotifications is a relationship which is defined in side your User model and your view is trying to fetch that method.

Comment: Actually, this 'Downloads" model has no relationship with unreadNotification. Other models like post, tag also has no belong to method.

Comment: That's the problem here there must be this **unreadNotifications and readNotifications** methods/relationship inside your User Model.

Comment: Ask your friend for this Model, he might help you with this as it's his code only.